# Does not storing a newly declared object cause a memory leak?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, java-memory-leaks

What I mean to say through the post title is - doing this:

```java
public static void makeNewObjectAndDoTask() {
    new SomeClass().doYourTask();
}
```

I have myself written such code in languages such Java and JavaScript - declaring a new object without storing it in a variable, JUST to call one of its methods. Does this cause memory leaks? ..or does the object get cleared at the end of the method-stack / gets freed by the Java Garbage Collector?

Should I just be doing this instead - for safety?:

```java
public static void makeNewObjectAndDoTask() {
    SomeClass obj = new SomeClass().doYourTask();
    obj = null;
    //System.gc(); // Perhaps also call the collector manually?
}
```

Comment: No memory leak in sight.

Comment: "does the object [...] gets freed by the Java Garbage Collector?" yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the commentors already answered, there is no memory leak in code like

```
public static void makeNewObjectAndDoTask() {
    new SomeClass().doYourTask();
}
```

at least in itself, assuming that the `SomeClass()` constructor and the `doYourTask()` methods don't create memory leaks.

Definitely, the garbage collector will clean up the SomeClass instance at some time in the future.

How does it work?

- Instances that are no longer accessible from program code will be garbage collected. Accessibility means being referenced in a variable, field, array element, method argument and so on.
- As soon as the `new SomeClass().doYourTask();` statement has finished, there is no way to access this individual `SomeClass` instance any more. So, it fulfills the garbage collection criteria.
- The next time the garbage collector runs, it can reclaim the memory occupied by the instance (and its fields, recursively, as long as they aren't referenced elsewhere).

The alternative code

```
public static void makeNewObjectAndDoTask() {
    SomeClass obj = new SomeClass().doYourTask();
    obj = null;
}
```

only delays the garbage collection opportunity, as it stores a reference in `obj`, thus making the instance accessible for at least a tiny additional period of time, until you assign `obj = null;`.

Manually calling the garbage collector as in `System.gc();` rarely is a good idea. It forces the GC to run (and to spend execution time on cleaning up memory), instead of relying on the JVM's highly optimized GC scheduling strategies. Don't do it unless you have a thorough understanding of the garbage collector, which led you to the conclusion that the GC strategy fails in your case.

We don't want OutOfMemoryErrors, and we don't want excessive time wasted for garbage collection, and the standard GC system does a very good job in both aspects.

Comment: Understood, thank you!~